# Turning off \pause during reverse scrolling

Tags: beamer

In `beamer`, is there a way to turn-off the `\pause` effect during reverse scrolling? That is, during my presentation, I would like to scroll back to a previous slide, but it is annoying to hit page up multiple times before getting to the slide I want.  I would like to keep `\pause` during forward scrolling, but NOT for backwards scroll.

Comment: No there isn't because a pause is actually an independent slide. Thus you will encounter it forward and backward directions. But there is a button on the navigation symbols that goes back a frame (not a slide) hence you can jump back to the previous frame.

Comment: Analogy for what TeX is *meant* for: How can I have my book skip Chapter 4 if I'm reading it backwards? I'm not saying using TeX for slides is a bad thing, I'm just advising to keep this in mind :)

Comment: The single steps of the pauses are individual pages in the pdf, so they can not be removed while being views. The closes thing what you could do is to add a button/hyperlink/etc to your slides which let you jump to the beginning of the frame.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds impossible and against the basic mechanics of `beamer`